# Why are site stats graph for beta sites not available to public?

Tags: feature-request, statistics, beta-sites

Currently, on all beta sites, the current site stats is placed prominently on the front page, which is great for knowing how the site is currently doing.

[image]

However, it doesn't say anything about the trend of the numbers - whether the site is sailing or it is sinking compared to the last month.

According to Madara Uchiha, our moderator on Anime & Manga SE, [a graphical representation of the stats are available, but to moderators only](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17792437#17792437).

**Disregarding data which are not already public**, [which are hidden for a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106306/why-are-stats-not-public-information), I can't see any reason why we are not allowed access to graphical representation of **public** site statistics. In fact, there is already a third-party app that scraps the information from the home page and [draws up some nice graph showing the site statistics over time](http://codemanteau.com/stacker/?siteId=225).

**Can we have a beautiful visualization on how our beta sites evolve over time, from pony to unicorn?**

[image: Ponyta] [image: Rapidash]

<sub><sup>Images <s>stolen</s> borrowed from Bulbapedia</sup></sub>

Comment: The graphs Madara mentions are moderator only on *all* sites, not just beta ones.

Answer (score 6):

This type of information is available publicly from the Data Explorer. Over on [Moderators.SE](http://moderators.stackexchange.com), I've utilized this data to show trends previously. The query was originally written by [roflf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241497/rolfl). It shows

- Questions Asked per week
- Answer Accepts per week
- Answers given per week
- Comments per week
- Question votes per week
- Answer Votes per week
- New users per week

Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=150#graph), adjusted for Anime.SE.

[image: Anime.SE Stats]

Comment: +1 I think this is a reasonable solution for the problem. It even contains data which are not clearly shown in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

They're not available because people fixate on them as if they were important, and they're only peripheral. They're also potentially commercially valuable. As ChrisF commented, a site's internal graphs are available to mods on graduated sites as well as beta ones.

If you really want to know about the health of your site, look at the quantity and quality of recent questions and answers on your front page. Look at how many users are active on your meta and in chat.

If you want, you can always track the Area51 stats yourself, as [several sites do already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230949/164022).

And if you really do need a data visualisation to look at over time, use the quantcast stats. For example, here are the stats for the [Sustainability Stack Exchange](http://Sustainability.StackExchange.com/), global weekly visitors for the last 3 months. You can click through for estimates of demographic and geographic splits, charts of pages, visitors, views, uniques - enough stats to saturate yourself with them.

[image]